# Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC creating 2d array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, access-violation

I'm trying to make a dynamic 2-dimensional array.

Here is my code:

```cpp
bool b_alloc_table_2_dim(int ***piTable, int iSizeX, int iSizeY)
{
    *piTable = new int*[iSizeX];
    for (int ii = 0; ii < iSizeX; ii++)
        *piTable[ii] = new int[iSizeY]; // here i get the exception
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int **x ;
    b_alloc_table_2_dim( &x, 3, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

I can't find anything wrong with the code. After calling my function x is supposed to point to the 2d array.

Comment: `0xcccccccc` should be recognized as uninitialized stack memory [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations/127404#127404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations/127404#127404)

Comment: [See this as to why your general approach is flawed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048).

Comment: You should use an actual container if you are writing c++. Are you writing c or c++ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[]` operator takes precedence over `*`. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

So the line

```
*piTable[ii] = new int[iSizeY];
```

is equivalent to

```
*(piTable[ii]) = new int[iSizeY];
```

what you wanted to write is:

```
(*piTable)[ii] = new int[iSizeY];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed it :)

Comment: @JakubWojcieszonek don't forget to also `delete` the dynamically allocated memory to avoid memory leaks and follow best coding practices.

Answer (score 0):

### Use an actual container

**Using an actual container avoids a lot of the types of issues that you have encountered.**

Instead of

```
int**
```

For a 2d array (a matrix) a more suitable data structure could be

```
std::array< std::array<int, cols>, rows>
```

if the sizes is known at compile time.

---

If not, it's probably best to just use a single vector ala.

```
auto my_array2d = std::vector<int>(rows*cols);//array now has 'rows*cols' elements of '0'
```

and handle indexing yourself.

The best thing is of course to use a library like perhaps [eigen](/questions/tagged/eigen) or [boost](/questions/tagged/boost)

Comment: Thank you, but I am supposed to do it that way according to the assignment.